# In Jetpack Compose Vector Image is not working with Android 5.0

Tags: android, svg, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to import a vector like so:

```
    Image(
        modifier = Modifier,
        painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.intro_svg_1),
        contentDescription = ""
    )
```

It looks like it works in all versions of android except `Android 5.0 (API level 21)`.

Following is is the error log:

```
2022-01-12 12:58:26.627 20063-20063/app.erpflow E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: app.erpflow, PID: 20063
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f0700a1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1457)
        at androidx.compose.ui.res.PainterResources_androidKt.painterResource(PainterResources.android.kt:61)
        at app.erpflow.screens.set_up_activity.page1.Screen1Kt.Screen1(Screen1.kt:31)
        at app.erpflow.screens.set_up_activity.ViewPagerIntroKt$ViewPagerIntro$1$1.invoke(ViewPagerIntro.kt:54)
        at app.erpflow.screens.set_up_activity.ViewPagerIntroKt$ViewPagerIntro$1$1.invoke(ViewPagerIntro.kt:51)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at com.google.accompanist.pager.Pager$Pager$7$1$1.invoke(Pager.kt:326)
        at com.google.accompanist.pager.Pager$Pager$7$1$1.invoke(Pager.kt:315)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:135)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListScopeImpl$items$1$1.invoke(LazyListScopeImpl.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.list.LazyListScopeImpl$items$1$1.invoke(LazyListScopeImpl.kt:41)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:228)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.saveable.SaveableStateHolderImpl.SaveableStateProvider(SaveableStateHolder.kt:84)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$content$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:103)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.layout.LazyLayoutItemContentFactory$CachedItemContent$content$1.invoke(LazyLayoutItemContentFactory.kt:94)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:251)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2$1$1.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:251)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3337)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2582)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt__DerivedStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(DerivedState.kt:247)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(Unknown Source)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2571)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2522)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:478)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:748)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2987)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:433)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:269)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState.access$subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:154)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:244)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.SubcomposeLayoutState$subcompose$2.invoke(SubcomposeLayout.kt:241)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.withNoObservations(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:142)
        at androidx
```

Is there a workaround or shall I make it **.png**? In that case it works fine but I would prefer **.svg** for a crisper image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the **.svg** files have been saved to `drawable-v24` as **.xml**. I moved all the files to `drawable` folder and it works fine.

[image]

Comment: my svg is already in drawable folder